# dark area in react-vis example

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I'm trying to use react-vis. If I use the privided examples, I get black areas between the lines. What do I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I missed some installation instruction:

"Include the built main CSS file in your HTML page or via SASS:

@import "./node_modules/react-vis/dist/style";"

Answer (score 5):

Import this css file

`import '../node_modules/react-vis/dist/style.css';`

OR

Use
`style={{ fill: 'none' }}`
It worked for me in line chart.

[image]

Comment: You can import it to your .scss file as well: @import "./node_modules/react-vis/dist/style";

Answer (score 3):

add the below CSS

```
.react-vis-magic-css-import-rule {
  display: inherit;
}

.rv-treemap {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.rv-treemap__leaf {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.rv-treemap__leaf--circle {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rv-treemap__leaf__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.rv-xy-plot {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  position: relative;
}

.rv-xy-plot canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.rv-xy-plot .rv-xy-canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.rv-xy-plot__inner {
  display: block;
}

.rv-xy-plot__axis__line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #e6e6e9;
}

.rv-xy-plot__axis__tick__line {
  stroke: #e6e6e9;
}

.rv-xy-plot__axis__tick__text {
  fill: #6b6b76;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.rv-xy-plot__axis__title text {
  fill: #6b6b76;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.rv-xy-plot__grid-lines__line {
  stroke: #e6e6e9;
}

.rv-xy-plot__circular-grid-lines__line {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #e6e6e9;
}

.rv-xy-plot__circular-grid-lines__line {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #e6e6e9;
}

.rv-xy-plot__series,
.rv-xy-plot__series path {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.rv-xy-plot__series--line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.rv-crosshair {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 11px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.rv-crosshair__line {
  background: #47d3d9;
  width: 1px;
}

.rv-crosshair__inner {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
}

.rv-crosshair__inner__content {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #3a3a48;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.rv-crosshair__inner--left {
  right: 4px;
}

.rv-crosshair__inner--right {
  left: 4px;
}

.rv-crosshair__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rv-crosshair__item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rv-hint {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.rv-hint__content {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #3a3a48;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend.horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item {
  color: #3a3a48;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 9px 10px;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item.horizontal .rv-discrete-color-legend-item__title {
  margin-left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item__color {
  background: #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 14px;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item__title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item.disabled {
  color: #b8b8b8;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rv-discrete-color-legend-item.clickable:hover {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.rv-search-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rv-search-wrapper__form {
  flex: 0;
}

.rv-search-wrapper__form__input {
  width: 100%;
  color: #a6a6a5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e4;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 0 0 9px;
  outline: 0;
}

.rv-search-wrapper__contents {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.rv-continuous-color-legend {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.rv-continuous-color-legend .rv-gradient {
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.rv-continuous-size-legend {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.rv-continuous-size-legend .rv-bubbles {
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rv-continuous-size-legend .rv-bubble {
  background: #d8d9dc;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.rv-continuous-size-legend .rv-spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.rv-legend-titles {
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.rv-legend-titles__center,
.rv-legend-titles__left,
.rv-legend-titles__right {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rv-legend-titles__center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.rv-legend-titles__right {
  right: 0;
}

.rv-radial-chart .rv-xy-plot__series--label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: adding a comment for search visibility; this solution helps style react-vis crosshair as needed as well

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to obtain it from a cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis@1.11.7/dist/style.css" />
```